# Php string htmlspecialchars and tags?

Tags: php, tags, chat, message, htmlspecialchars

I need some help with my chat script which does not allow html tags right now.

I need it to allow `<b>` `<u>` and `<i>` tags so users could edit their texts.

My system turns urls to links, so there is some kind of base system for some html, but i need those text editing systems.
Here are the files to play with, theyre as text documents on my own domain: http://shadowkiro.net/help_needed_stackowerflow

I have been trying to search answers from here and there, finding something about strip_tags and string htmlspecialchars. They look like something I would need to make my html tags work and what i need to put in chat_room.js file, but I have absolutely no idea how to make them as a code cooperate with my chat_room.tpl site where all the chat messages are sent to chat window. 
In chat_room.tpl is also this chat scripts own bold, underline and italic scripts, which will bold, italic or underline the whole text instead part of it. I need an option to bold, italic or underline only part of the text.

Here is small printscreen of how my chat looks like:
http://i1110.photobucket.com/albums/h448/shadowkiro/chat_window.png

Help me?

I am n00b with this and sorry for my bad english, this is not my native language.

---

I have tried this in chat_room.js but it did not work.

```
// B I U codes here

    if (typeof(converted_parts[i])=='undefined' && 0==msg_parts[i].indexOf('<b>') && msg_parts[i]) {
              msg_parts[i]='<b>'+htmlspecialchars(msg_parts[i])+'</b>';
```

`}`

```
    if (typeof(converted_parts[i])=='undefined' && 0==msg_parts[i].indexOf('<i>') && msg_parts[i]) {
              msg_parts[i]='<i>'+htmlspecialchars(msg_parts[i])+'</i>';
```

`}`

```
    if (typeof(converted_parts[i])=='undefined' && 0==msg_parts[i].indexOf('<u>') && msg_parts[i]) {
              msg_parts[i]='<u>'+htmlspecialchars(msg_parts[i])+'</u>';
```

`}`

Comment: RTLM? http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: I have been reading that page also, but not kinda getting all stuff from it. I edited to my first post what I have tried.

Comment: not sure what your code is supposed to accomplish. that's not PHP. javascript, maybe? you can't use php functions in JS code, or vice versa.

Comment: Oh... It is supposed to allow html characters like <i> <u> and <b> in those script files I have linked to my guestion. ^^'

Comment: that'd be fine, but you're calling a php function using a javascript argument, within javascript code. utterly impossible. php executes on the server, javascript executes on the client browser. you canNOT mix the two languages like this.

Comment: That would explain a lot... Then I should somehow make that thing in javascript language.

Answer (score 2):

Use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), It will allow you to create a white list of HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

First do `htmlspecialchars()` then replace the outputted code with

```
<?php
$string=htmlspecialchars($string);

$string = 'any text <i>';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = "/&lt;i&gt;/"; // for<i>
$patterns[1] = "/&lt;b&gt;/"; // for<b>
$patterns[2] = "/&lt;u&gt;/"; // for<u>

$replacements = array();

$replacements[0] = '<i>';
$replacements[1] = '</b>';
$replacements[2] = '</u>';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
?>
```